# Rm and Egrep -v combo

Tags: linux, unix, grep, solaris, rm

I want to remove all the logs except the current log and the log before that.
These log files are created after 20 minutes.So the files names are like

```
abc_23_19_10_3341.log
 abc_23_19_30_3342.log
 abc_23_19_50_3241.log
 abc_23_20_10_3421.log
```

where 23 is today's date(might include yesterday's date also)
19 is the hour(7 o clock),10,30,50,10 are the minutes.

In this case i want i want to keep  abc_23_20_10_3421.log which is the current log(which is currently being writen) and abc_23_19_50_3241.log(the previous one)
and remove the rest.

I got it to work by creating a folder,putting the first files in that folder and removing the files and then deleting it.But that's too long...

I also tried this

```
files_nodelete=`ls -t | head -n 2 | tr '\n' '|'`
rm *.txt | egrep -v "$files_nodelete"
```

but it didnt work.But if i put ls instead of rm it works.

I am an amateur in linux.So please suggest a simple idea..or a logic..xargs rm i tried but it didnt work.

Also read about mtime,but seems abit complicated since I am new to linux

Working on a solaris system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guyz for all the answers.
I found my answer

```
files=`ls -t *.txt | head -n 2 | tr '\n' '|' | rev |cut -c 2- |rev`
rm `ls -t | egrep -v "$files"`
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try the logadm tool in Solaris, it might be the simplest way to rotate logs. If you just want to get things done, it will do it.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/logadm-1m.html

Answer (score 1):

It is usually not a good idea to use ls to point to files. Some files may cause havoc (files which have a [Newline] or a weird character in their name are the usual exemples ....).

Using shell globs : Here is an interresting way : we count the files newer than the one we are about to remove!

```
pattern='abc*.log'
for i in $pattern ; do
   [ -f "$i" ] || break ;
   #determine if this is the most recent file, in the current directory 
   #  [I add -maxdepth 1 to limit the find to only that directory, no subdirs]
   if [ $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$pattern" -type f -newer "$i" -print0 | tr -cd '\000' | tr '\000' '+' | wc -c) -gt 1 ];
   then
       #there are 2 files more recent than $i that match the pattern 
       #we can delete $i
       echo rm "$i" # remove the echo only when you are 100% sure that you want to delete all those files !
   else
       echo "$i is one of the 2 most recent files matching '${pattern}', I keep it"
   fi
done
```

I only use the globbing mechanism to feed filenames to "find", and just use the terminating "0" of the -printf0 to count the outputed filenames (thus I have no problems with any special characters in those filenames, I just need to know how many files were outputted)

`tr -cd "\000"` will keep only the `\000`, ie the terminating NUL character outputed by print0. Then I translate each `\000` to a single `+` character, and I count them with the `wc -c`. If I see 0, "$i" was the most recent file. If I see 1, "$i" was the one just a bit older (so the find sees only the most recent one). And if I see more than 1, it means the 2 files (mathching the pattern) that we want to keep are newer than "$i", so we can delete "$i"

I'm sure someone will step in with a better one, but the idea could be reused, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution similar (but working) to your try this:

```
ls abc*.log | sort | head -n-2 | xargs rm
```

`ls abc*.log`: list all files, matching the pattern `abc*.log`
`sort`: sorts this list lexicographical (by name) from oldes to to newest logfile
`head -n-2`: return all but the last two entry in the list (you can give `-n` a negativ count too)
`xargs rm`: compose the `rm` command with the entries from stdin

If there are two or less files in the directory, this command will return an error like

```
rm: missing operand
```

and will not delete any files.

Comment: You can avoid the complaint from `rm` by adding `-f`.  Be cautious about that, but it is what you want.  If you're sure that the names don't contain spaces or other untoward characters, then parsing `ls` output is not dangerous.  The question is whether you can be sure.